# Copying bone keyframes to make a longer loop

Tags: bones, keyframes

I'm trying to extend the running cyle of [this object from Sketchfab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdyq4.jpg) in Blender.
It is an .fbx import with an armature.

The run cycle lasts for 12 frames. I would like to loop it over 250 frames.

I can copy and paste the object keyframes, which duplicates the location and rotation keyframes correctly.

How do I correctly copy the bone keyframes?
Do I have to go into each bone individually and copy them?  Is there a better way?

[image]

Comment: The Non-Linear Animation window is made for this, switch your Dope Sheet to Action Editor, you need to push down your aciton into the NLA, open the NLA, select the yellow strip it has created, and in the N panel > Strip > Action Clip > increase the Repeat value. That said, with this method, your armature will stay static, you'll need to move it forward or use a Follow Path and syncrhonize the speeds so that the feet don't slide

Comment: it will also depends on how you want to use the animation. Also, is the root moving or not? etc...

Answer (score 3):

Provided your keyframes are cyclic (start and end pose is the same) you can go into the dope sheet (or Graph Editor) window, select all bones and then all channels (make sure none are hidden), then hit 
SHIFT + E
and select Make Cyclic (F-Curve Modifier). This will work fine if your cat is supposed to walk forever. You can modify the framerange for each individual channel, however ALT-clicking on a property of the modifier seems be *not* tranfered to all the other channels, like it would be in the properties panel.
So if you want to limit the frame range without going throug all the channels individually, the NLA method proposed by @moonboots is better.

Comment: Is there a quick way to select all the bones?  I can only see the keyframes when I select each nested bone one by one

Comment: In pose mode press ALT + H, to make sure none are hidden, press A to select all. If there are still bones missing, check the layer visibility in the armature properties.